# Is this derivation of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ correct?

Tags: derivatives

Derivatives show us how fast something is changing at any point. For example; the gradient of the graph of $y = x^2$ at any point is twice the value of $x$ thereat. The process of finding the derivation of a gradient / slope of a function $y=f(x)$ or $y = x^2$ is as follow.

Pick any two points $A$ and $B$ close to each other on the curve of $y =x^2$. The coordinates of $A$ on the curve are $(x, y)$ or $(x, x^2)$. Add $Δx$ at $A$ as usual. When $x$ increases by $Δx$, then $y$ increases by $Δy$. The $x$ changes from $x$ to $(x +Δx)$ while $y$ changes from $y$ to $(y + Δy)$ or $f(x)$ to $(x+Δx)^2$. Thus the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of $B$ on the curve are $(x + Δx, y + Δy)$ or $([x+Δx, (x+Δx)^2].$ Now the instantaneous rate of change is given by

$$\frac{Δy}{Δx} = \frac{[(x + Δx)^2 – x^2]}{[x + Δx - x]}$$

$$\frac{Δy}{Δx} = \frac{[x^2 + Δx^2+2xΔx − x^2]}{ Δx}$$

$$\frac{Δy}{Δx} = \frac{[2x + Δx]}{ 1}$$

Reduce $Δx$ close to zero by taking limit ($Δx$ to $dx$ and $Δy$ to $dy$)

$$\frac{Δy}{Δx} = 2x + dx$$

$$\frac{Δy}{Δx} = 2x \tag1\label{eq1} $$
OR

$$dy = 2x.dx \tag2\label{eq2}$$

ABC is an infinitesimal triangle made by $dx, dy$, and hypotenuse or slope of tangent where point $A$ and $C$ are always on the curve. Length of $AB$ = Base = $dx$, Length of $BC$ = Perpendicular= $dy$ and Length of Hypotenuse = $AC$. $\angle CAB$ or $\angle BAC$ is the slope of a tangent

According to the aforementioned $\eqref{eq1}$ or $\eqref{eq2}$

•$\frac{dy}{dx}$ is directly proportional to $x$ or $\angle CAB$ is directly proportional to $x$.

• $dx$ is indirectly proportional to $x$ OR $x$ is inversely proportional to $dx$.

• $dy$ is directly proportional to $x.dx$ or $dx$

The length of $dx > dy$ when $\angle CAB < 45$ degrees The length of $dx = dy$ when $\angle CAB = 45$ degrees The length of $dx < dy$ when $\angle CAB > 45$ degrees.

The proportionality of both the $\angle CAB$ and $dy$ with $x$ are in contradiction with the proportionality of $x$ and $dx$ in the triangle $ABC$ after probing the equation of $\frac{dy}{dx} = 2x$ beyond its derivation on a graph of $y = x^2$. When $x$ increases; $dx$ decreases, $dy$ increases, and $\angle CAB$ increases. This means $AC$ also increases and ultimately SECANT when $x$ increases. Our goal is to bring $dx, dy$ and $AC$ to zero (not away from zero either positively or negatively - Point $C$ has to be on the curve) or secant to tangent by reducing them close to zero but here $dx$ heads toward zero but $dy$ and $AC$ increases when $x $ increases on axis mathematically.

Although the difference in the length of $dx$ and $dy$ can be noticeable clearly on the graph if we examine the triangle $ABC$ at two different points for a gradient ($\frac{dy}{dx}$), say when an $\angle BAC = 0.1$ degrees and 89.9 degrees on the curve but UNIT CIRCLE is the best example for observing the change in an $\angle CAB$ (say 0.1 and 89.9 degrees) of a triangle $ABC$ for $dy$ and $dx$ and the comparison of their lengths.

$RISE = dy = 2x$ and $RUN = dx = 1$ (always constant) in a GRADIENT of 1 in $2x$ which we obtained from the $\eqref{eq1}$ of $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2x}{1}$ at any point on the curve when there is no difference between secant and tangent – No idea how do we get $\frac{dy}{dx} = 2x.dx$ but above said contradiction may be due to the introduction of another curve of $y =(x+dx)^2$ at a point where we seize $x$ or $y=x^2$  deliberately and introduce delta $x$ OR when function $y = f(x)$ changed to $y=f(x+Δx)^2$. The value of $x$ has reached to its maximum value instead of unlimited when a curve $y=x^2$ doesn’t continue anymore at a point where we introduce delta $x$ or $dx$ as $y=x^2$ and $y =(x+dx)^2$ are two different types of curve (two diffrent functions).

Further, integration is the reverse process of differentiation. Although delta $x$ or $dx$ is ignored during the process of derivation of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ because of their small values but we can’t ignore them in the process of integration which makes a lot of difference in summation. They can’t be disappeared forever and should resurface during the process of integration or summation.

Similarly, $dy$ is the small vertical change in $y$, therefore, we take the sum of all the small vertical lengths [dy(s)] not the whole slice or y-coordinate(s) from zero to its value on the curve when we integrate both sides of the equation of $dy = 2xdx$ but it turns into function of $x^2$ or area under the graph – no idea how but summation of vertical lengths on a graph gives vertical length only not curve?

The derivation of the natural relationship of a gradient of 1 in $2x$ at any point with $y=x^2$ or $\frac{dy}{dx}=2x$ is still unbeknownst to illuminates - Anyone who is in agreement with all above unless satisfied by logic.

Below figure may help with the above.

[Image](https://i.postimg.cc/QCH2mBYy/IMG-E3179.jpg)[image]

[image]

Comment: Ok, but next time. I'm a new user of this site.

Comment: @YouKnowMe, you edited to make all the superscripts subscripts or in-line?

Comment: i just added a figure in the link that might be helpful

Comment: @YouKnowMe He means you messed up. You made things that should be $(x+\Delta x)^2$ into $(x+\Delta x)2$ and $x^2$ into $x_2$. I'd fix it myself, but it's a bit tedious editing large amounts of MathJax on the phone.

Comment: Sorry, it was all my fault. I didn't know about MathJax.

Comment: Your explanations are tedious and obscure, especially with a figure that it unreachable. What claim are you trying to prove ?

Comment: @EEK mathematically the concept of  integrals and differentiation are defined independently and they are linked by fundamental theorem of calculus, that too for restricted types of functions.

Comment: @ Infinity_hunter: you may be right but I just add another picture for more clarity or detail.

Comment: @EEK can you put what is your claim or conclusion in the question , it would really help others to know about your arguments more concisely.

Comment: Infinity_hunter: Not sure what to write but x^2 = 2x means that, for the function x^2, the slope or "rate of change" at any point is 2x. This is perfectly correct but the question is how is 2x derived from y=x^2 as the use of dy/dx approach seems in question to me due to the aforementioned reasons. IMPOV, we need to find another derivation of slope (2x) from function y=x^2 that is absolutely correct.

Answer (score 6):

The derivative of a univariate function $f(x)$ at the point $x$ is defined to be

$$f'(x):=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$ when this limit exists. Full stop. This definition is non-negociable.

The geometric interpretation is that of the local slope of the graph of the function, and this is correct as well.

Comment: +1 for the phrase " non-negotiable "

Answer (score 0):

As $\dfrac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}\approx\dfrac{dy}{dx}=2x$, for small $x$, $\Delta x\gg\Delta y$ and for large $x$, $\Delta x\ll\Delta y$. Really nothing weird.

Comment: @YouKnowMe: because they address the question very differently.